# Google App Engine Multitenancy API

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, multi-tenant

According to the [GAE docs on the Multitenancy API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/overview):

> Multitenancy is the name given to a software architecture in which one instance of an application, running on a remote server, serves many client organizations (also known as tenants).

But isn't this what *every* web application is? Dozens, hundreds, maybe even thousands of users all logging in to the system, accessing the same software, but from inside the context of their own "user accounts"? Or is Google's Multitenancy API some kind of API for developing generic data abstraction layers that can be used as backends for multiple apps?

I guess I don't get the meaning of a "Google multi-tenant" app, and as such, don't understand the purpose or usefulness of the Multitenancy API. Thanks in advance for any clarity here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multitenancy here doesn't refer to users of your app as such, but 'instances' of your app with 'separate' datastores.

They aren't really separate instances or separate datastores, as those requests might be served by a shared instance and they are definitely talking to the same datastore. However, by using the API you can set up your app so that the data is partitioned into separate namespaces which don't pollute each other.

If you have only one user on your app, then multi-users and multi-tenanting is pretty much the same thing. If you have multiple users, then generally you'll be sharing data between the users. If so, you can use multitenancy to share data within only a certain group of users and partition the rest off in their own tenancy.

As jtahlborn rightly states, each of our GAE apps is already a tenant on the GAE infrastructure. We aren't able to share data between different apps because they are completely partitioned from each other.

As Dave says, we could implement multitenancy ourselves by adding some kind of domain name or partition id to all our data. The API just gives an easier way to do that.

Comment: how can we separate billing for different tenants? is there a way to do it?

Comment: @xtrahelp.com are you talking about GAE billing or your own separate billing for tenants? it's probably better posed as a separate question on SO - if you create one I'll take a crack at answering that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the standard way that multitenancy is implemented: You add a "tenant ID" field to one or more tables, then include that ID in a WHERE clause. And you index that field.

You could take the same approach in App Engine, adding an indexed property to some of your entities to hold a tenant ID, carefully including that ID in GQL WHERE clauses (or a filters). This'll cost you a bit more on writes (for the two indexes on that property), and more if the ID participates in queries that include other filters, as those would require additional composite indexes that include the ID.

Or you user our multitenancy API, which gives you the same effect without the additional costs for index writes. You get slightly simpler code, and less expense.

Comment: In addition, all (well almost) the other services are Namespace API aware. Thus, by setting the namespace when you start your processing, all GAE services calls you make will be restricted to the specified namespace/tenant. The segregation is better enforced by relying on this global API than by trying to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is whose tenants you are talking about.  GAE was multi-tenant from day one in that each program(tenant) ran in a common GAE infrastructure.  however, initially, your program itself just managed one body of data (when GAE was first released).  the GAE "multi-tenancy API" enables your single program to manage its(your) own tenants (so *your* tenants as opposed to *GAE's* tenants).

to state it concisely and confusingly: the "multi-tenancy API" allows you to manage your own tenants(users) within a single GAE program, which is in turn hosted as a tenant(program) within the GAE infrastructure.

in theory, of course, you could always have done this from day 1 in GAE, but all the work for managing the data between your tenants would have been handled in your code.  the "multi-tenancy API" attempts to remove that pain from the programmer and make it much simpler to segment the data within your program.